# For $v$ in tangent space of a manifold what is the expression for a composition of two function

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**Definition 1:** Suppose $M$ a differentiable manifold and $p\in M$.
A funtion $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $p \in M$ iff $\exists U_p \subset M$ : $f:U_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.

**Definition 2:**$D =${set of all differentiable functions at $p \in M$}

**Definition 3:** Suppose $M$ a differentiable manifold and $p\in M$.
A tangent vector at $p\in M$ is an operator $v:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad : \quad f \mapsto v(f)$ with
i) $v(mf+ng)=mv(f)+nv(g) \quad \forall f,g \in D$
ii)$v(fg)=v(f)g(p)+f(p)v(g) \quad \forall f,g \in D$

**Definition 4:** $T_{p}M=${set of all tangent vectors at $p \in M$} \

Now for $f \in D$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, what is the expression for $v(g \circ f)$?

Answer (score 0):

It is
$$
v(g\circ f)(p)=g'(f(p))\cdot v(f)(p)
$$

Hint: Remember that
$$
v(F)(p)=dF_p (v)
$$

**Added**
Alternative way: Remember that if you fix a coordinate chart around $p$, $(U,\varphi=(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$, then $\partial_{x_i}$ is a basis for the tangent vectors. Your statement applied to every $\partial_{x_i}$ is nothing but the usual chain rule.

Comment: I know that $d(g \circ f )_p = dg_{f(p)} \circ df_p$ But I’m confused because g is a real function. It seem obvious that the result is the one you mentioned above ( as using chain rule in a classic function) but I can’t write a detailed proof.

Comment: Basically i can't understand how the multiplication comes up

Comment: The maps $dF_x$ are linear maps, so their composition is matrix multiplication. In the case of $g$, is a 1x1 matrix...